# is there a way to comment a twitter post with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, social-media

is there a way to leave a comment on a twitter post with python? So is there a library which can do this?
Something like where you put the link from the post, and the comment to send.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use tweepy library, and reply to a tweet using [update_status](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.update_status) function.

Mention a user using @, and use tweet id.

```
 reply = api.update_status("Hello world to @username", tweet.id)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a Twitter bot that might be able to comment on post, there are many examples of bots that post a comment from the news website or snippet of news on Twitter. I don't think that there is an all-in-one library that can do this, but you can build your own bot in python using these libraries.

```
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
bs4==0.0.1
lxml==3.6.0
nltk==3.2.1
oauthlib==1.0.3
Pillow==3.2.0
requests==2.9.1
requests-oauthlib==0.6.1
simplejson==3.8.2
six==1.10.0
tweepy==3.5.0
Twython
```

The program below will help you post all replies automatically. And it has a delay so that Twitter won't flag your account for spamming. You need authentication and the Twitter id [not yours] to tell the bot where it has to comment.

```
id = str(id)
if id in ids_replied_to:
    print('')
    print('Skipped as already replied to')
    print('')
    print('')
else:
    twitter_handle = '@' + screen_name
    message = twitter_handle + " " + random.choice(rand_message)
    twitter.update_status(status=message, in_reply_to_status_id=id)
    print("Tweeted: %s" % message)
    id = int(id)
    ids_replied_to.append(id)
    with open('ids_replied_to.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
        filehandle.writelines("%s\n" % place for place in ids_replied_to)
    # delay so that it doesn't look like the program is spamming Twitter
    time.sleep(5)
```